# iPhone - Sync between iPhone Settings and Settings in App

Tags: iphone, settings

I've a requirement where I'll have settings bundle which will show app in iPhone Settings.
Also Application itself will have a settings page. 
Both App in iPhone settings and Application settings will show same info.
I know how to read settings bundle details and update in application settings.
But how to do it in other way. Means, when user updates something in application settings, how can i change in settings bundle so that it will reflect in iPhone settings?

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several packages out there that will make this easy.  [In App Settings Kit](http://www.inappsettingskit.com/) is the one I have heard the most about.